# ActionListener with a custom Button class (Java)

Tags: java, swing, button, action, actionlistener

I dont need an outright answer for this. just a suggestion on how this problem could be fixed. I am trying to add an action listener to MyButton so that i can call the action performed method in my main class

this is the buttons constructed. they show up and everything works on them minus the actionlistener.

```
upButton = new MyButton(upStaticImageLocation, upRolledImageLocation, upClickedImageLocation);
    upButton.addActionListener(this);
    downButton = new MyButton(downStaticImageLocation, downRolledImageLocation, downClickedImageLocation);
    downButton.addActionListener(this);
```

this is the MyButton class with action listener method.

```
public class MyButton extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

private Dimension size = new Dimension(32, 32);

private Image staticImage;
private Image rolledImage;
private Image clickedImage;

private ArrayList<ActionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener>();

public MyButton(String staticImage, String rolledImage, String clickedImage) {
    super();

    this.staticImage = new ImageIcon(staticImage).getImage();
    this.rolledImage = new ImageIcon(rolledImage).getImage();
    this.clickedImage = new ImageIcon(clickedImage).getImage();

    enableInputMethods(true);
    addMouseListener(this);

    setSize(size.width, size.height);
    setFocusable(true);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *call the action performed method in my main class*?

Comment: @Forager The question relates to Swing not FX

Comment: Oh, sorry; I should have noticed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a lot of work which has already been done...see [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details.

However, `JComponent` already provides access to an `EventListenerList`, so you don't need your `listeners` `List`, for example...

```
public class MyButton extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

    //private ArrayList<ActionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener>();

    public MyButton(String staticImage, String rolledImage, String clickedImage) {
        //...
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }
```

Okay, but how do you trigger the event?

```
protected void fireActionPerformed() {
    ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
    if (listeners != null) {
        ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Awesome button action");
        for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.actionPerformed(evt);
        }
    } 
}
```

So whenever you want to send an `ActionPerformed` event, you simply call the `fireActionPerformed` method within your button

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly but think that instead of :

```
downButton.addActionListener(this);
```

you must use:

```
downButton.addActionListener(downButton);
```

since you are trying to add action listener somewhere outside MyButton so 'this' does not point to instance of MyButton and MyButton must implement ActionListener ie this method:

```
@Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  // doo your woodoo here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I should post the method that fixed the action listeners and made the whole thing work. Thanks to madProgrammer for his answer.

```
     public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

 protected void fireActionPerformed() {
        ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
        if (listeners != null) {
            ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Awesome button action");
            for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.actionPerformed(evt);
            }
        } 
    }

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    fireActionPerformed();
}
```

just needed the call on fireActionPerformed when the mouse was clicked.